# How to check in Ruby if an array contains other arrays?

Tags: ruby

I have a multidimensional array like this:

```
main_array = [ [["a","b","c"],["d","e"]], [["e","f"],["g","h"]]  ]
```

And I would like to check whether `main_array` contains other arrays.
I've thought that this will work `main_array.include?(Array)`, but i was wrong.

Comment: `a.any? { |e| Array === e }` also works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question directly, I will use [`#grep`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) method

```
 main_array.grep(Array).empty?
```

This will ensure that, if your `main_array` contains at least one element as `Array`, if returns `false`.

```
 main_array.grep(Array).size == main_array.size
```

This will tell you, if all elements are array or not.

Comment: Good answer, but should is the logic not reversed in the first example?

Comment: @hirolau First one is for to check *if any element is an array or not*, the last to check *all elements are array or not*

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Enumerable#all?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) if you want to check that the main array contains all arrays.

```
main_array.all? { |item| item.is_a?(Array) }
```

or [Enumerable#any?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F)

```
main_array.any? { |item| item.is_a?(Array) }
```

if you want to check if `main_array` contains any arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Enumerable#any?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F):

```
main_array.any?{|element| element.is_a? Array}
```

The code you tried (`main_array.include?(Array)` didn't work because it's checking if the array `main_array` includes the class `Array`, e.g. `[Array].include?(Array) #=> true`).

Answer (score 1):

```
main_array != main_array.flatten
```